# Find model by a string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having a hard time finding the problem in this repository method:

```
public function findByString($string)
{
        return User::where('string', $string)->get();
}
```

It generates the correct SQL statement which I can run in Sequel Pro returning the right result.

However, when this method is called in Laravel (4.2), the result is always empty:

```
$this->user->findByString('something');
```

On the other side

```
$this->user->findOrFail(1);
```

Always returns the correct model.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Im just guessing that the col name is "string" right?

Comment: Yeah, that’s correct. The generated SQL statement looks like this and returns the correct row in Sequel Pro: `select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `string` LIKE 'something'`

Comment: And what about appending the '%' wildcard to the string and see if it returns a row?

Comment: I've already tried that, no luck here either… Exactly the same behaviour… works with raw SQL, but not with Eloquent.

Comment: if you try User::where('string', 'ilike', $string)->get() what does it do?

Comment: I think ILIKE is not supported in MySQL. Using LIKE does not change anything either…

Comment: like is supported in mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), I don't haven a clue then

Comment: Ok, you mentioned ILIKE, so it just was a typo I think. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return User::where('string', $string)->get();
```

Will return a collection that you can iterate through.

If you want the first instance back as an Eloquent model you can do this:

```
return User::where('string', $string)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I was assuming that `get()` is also returning an Eloquent model if there is only 1 result.

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make. You could make it even prettier by leveraging the magic where methods. ie `return User::whereString($string)->first();`